Help Needed to Identify the Sensor in Logitech M185 Mouse
I have opened a Logitech M185 mouse to identify the optical sensor used in it. On the bottom of the mouse, I found the label "02MF01." Unfortunately, the Logitech support team was unable to provide the technical details.
Does anyone have information about which sensor is used in this mouse or has a datasheet for it?
Thank you for your assistance!
Best regards,

A quick search for 02MF01 didn't find the sensor. To help get an answer are you able to take a picture of the sensor and/or measure the dimensions?

Wikipedia has detailed pictures of the optical sensor of a M185 board. According to these pictures 02MF01 is likely written on the lense. Here is a picture of the optical sensor module from the same source:

The label Capella003 means that the manufacturer is most likely Capella Microsystems, but there are no references to this module on their homepage. I highly doubt that there is public information available about this sensor.
